# Спрятать заголовок таблицы при скролинге вниз

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Есть таблица которая содержит в шапке много информации и занимает пол экрана телефона.
После шапки идут обычные ячейки (список друзей) но скрол этих друзей происходит на малом промежутке экрана (так как шапка занимает пространство)
Как сделать чтобы при скроле таблицы вниз шапка тоже прокручивалась и исчезала? (листая вниз шапка исчезла и листаешь друзей на весь экран)

Comment: Добавьте вашу шапку в headerTableView вашей таблицы

Comment: я ее и так добавляю методом `-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {`

Comment: у вас таблица plain  или grouped?

Comment: Таблица - Plain

Comment: @SergeiStralenia намек понял =) сделал на Grouped и все норм спасибо

Comment: @Northex не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут два варианта:
1. Cделать UITableView с типом grouped, тогда будет вызываться метод делегата `-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
2. Оставить тип таблицы plain и тогда:

```
UIView *headerTableView = CreateYourCustomViewHere;
tableView.tableHeaderView = headerTableView;
```

В вашей ситуации подходит 2 вариант я думаю.